# Generating list of binomial outcomes

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

As an example, imagine if I have a set of 3 coins and I want to generate a list of possible coin states. I know I can brutishly execute:

```
Join[Permutations[{1, 1, 1}], Permutations[{-1, 1, 1}], 
Permutations[{-1, -1, 1}], Permutations[{-1, -1, -1}]]
```

where the outcome is

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 
1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}}
```

as desired; however, I want to be able to choose the number of coins with a variable in a way that resembles

```
permlist[2]
{{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}
```

and

```
permlist[3]
{{1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 
1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}}
```

I feel like I'm overlooking some trivial combinatorics functions Mathematica has.

Comment: `Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]`.

Comment: Sigh, there it is. Thanks as usual JimB!